Reference request - Books for real and complex analytic functions on Banach spaces
Consider the following scenario. I have two Banach spaces $E$ and $F$ and a function $f: U \subset E \to F$, where $U$ is open. Suppose first that these are complex Banach spaces. Then, if $f$ is continuously Fréchet differentiable on $U$, one says it is analytic on $U$. In this case, it is infinitely often differentiable on $U$ and it can be represented by a Taylor expansion in a neighborhood of each point in $U$.
I would like to understand these definitions under a slightly different point of view. More concretely, I would like to understand it using the Taylor expansion where the derivatives are taken with respect to parameters instead of using the Fréchet derivatives:
$$f(\lambda x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k}}{k!}f^{(k)}(x) \tag{1}\label{1}$$
where, now:
$$f^{(k)}(x) = \frac{d^{k}}{d\lambda^{k}}f(\lambda x)\bigg{|}_{\lambda = 0}. \tag{2}\label{2}$$
I wanted to find a book where this Taylor expansion is discussed in relation of the definition of analyticity given before. Moreover, I also would like to understand how the situation is changed when the Banach spaces are real. In this case $f$ is called analytic if it is $C^{\infty}$ on $U$ and the errors in the Taylor expansion go to zero. If I use (\ref{1}), I have heard that analyticity is equivalent to proving (\ref{2}) exists for all $k$ and each $f^{(k)}(x)$ uniformly bounded (in $k$). I wanted to better understand these objects.

I do recommend the two following books:

Functional Analysis and Semi-groups by E. Hille and R. S. Phillips.
Complex Analysis in Banach Spaces by J. Mujica.

The first one is a big treatise in analysis, that in particular contains (most) of what you need about complex analysis in Banach spaces. In the second one, the sole focus is about complex analysis in Banach spaces, which I find to be more 'self-contained' if that's the only thing you need. In my opinion, in those two you will find almost all the 'basics' of the theory you may need.
